# 1 of my 3 screens is working, not recognizing 2 of them

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a amd 7970, works great.  I have 3 screens and they all worked fine until recently.  I  went on a vacation and my parents tore apart my room to put new floors in.  In the process they disconnected my whole computer setup.  After plugging everything back in where it belongs I start my computer up but it only shows the main screen.  They two side screens no longer have anything, they have no signal.  I go into the AMD vision control to rearrange my screens but it only shows my main screen, it doesn't even detect the other 2.  Any help/ideas is appreciated.

Comment: It is less likely that they altered software on the computer. The detection is (usually) based on connection (ID). I would check the cabling and power connections first.  Next I might go into the "device manager" and tear out all the monitors. This would require the "hidden devices tweak" and observing all ghosted monitor items. After uninstalling all the leftovers, with the monitors removed, I would re-boot then reconnect the monitors one at a time and hope.